# How to replicate Jinja2 macros with JS/React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jinja2

I'm trying to use React on an existing project and I tackled everything except for one thing; I can't use [Jinja2 macros](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#macros). I use them to create a dynamic list with multiple items.

Set arguments:

```
{% set botnewsArgs = [
  ("channel", "Sets the channel to send bot news to"),
  ("toggle", "Toggles posting bot news")
] -%}
```

Create entries from them:

```
{% macro arg(arg_name, arg_description) -%}
<hr>
  <p>{{ arg_name }}</p>
  <small>{{ arg_description }}</small>
{%- endmacro %}
```

Use them with the parent entry:

```
{% macro main_expand(name, description, cmdargs) -%}
<li class="list-group-item border">
  <button>{{ name }}</button>
  <small>{{ description }}</small>
  <div class="args">
    {% for arg_name, arg_description in cmdargs %}
    {{ arg(arg_name, arg_description) }}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</li>
{%- endmacro %}
```

I set all this in a [command_args.html](https://github.com/pen-mb/gw2bot-site/blob/master/templates/command_args.html) file to import and use in [commands.html](https://github.com/pen-mb/gw2bot-site/blob/master/templates/commands.html). You can see the site live at [gw2bot.info/commands](https://gw2bot.info/commands)

I tried creating functions in JS such as:

```
const arg = (argName, argDescription) => {
  <React.Fragment>
    <hr />
    <p>{argName}</p>
    <small>{argDescription}</small>
  </React.Fragment>
}
```

and:

```
const mainExpand = (name, description) => {
  <React.Fragment>
    <li class="list-group-item border">
      <button>{{ name }}</button>
      <small>{{ description }}</small>
      <div class="args">
        {arg()}
        {}
      </div>
    </li>
  </React.Fragment>
}
```

but I am at a loss when it comes to putting them together and get the same functionality from Jinja2 macros.

Is it possible to replicate this with JS/React or is there a better approach to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you do something like this?

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const Arg = ({ argName, argDescription }) =>
  <React.Fragment>
    <hr />
    <p>{argName}</p>
    <small>{argDescription}</small>
  </React.Fragment>;

const MainExpand = ({ name, description }) =>
  <React.Fragment>
    <li class="list-group-item border">
      <button>{ name }</button>
      <small>{ description }</small>
      <div class="args">
        <Arg name={name} description={description} />
      </div>
    </li>
  </React.Fragment>;

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MainExpand argName="John Snow" argDescription="I know nothing!" /> 
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Have two components Arg and MainExpand and render Arg in MainExpand.